# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError with MNIST, [55000] vs. [10000]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through the code from this presentation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2nnJ4g6N0&t=20m28s and am getting this error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]`

I've already worked through a few errors regarding tensor shape/dimensions, but have no idea how to specifically understand this let alone correct it.

I'm new to tf and any advice is much appreciated, here is the code:

```
# 1 ~ import tf + data
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

#2 ~ paras + init
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

#3 ~ model + correct answers
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) # one-hot encoding

#4 ~ loss function
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y))

#5 ~ correct answer + % accuracy
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y, 1), tf.argmax(Y_, 1)) # one-hot decoding
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))

#6 ~ optimizer and training step
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003) # learning-rate
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

#7 ~ session and training loop
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    # load a batch of images and correct answers
    batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_data = {X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}

    # train
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

    # success?
    a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)

    # success on test data?
    test_data = {X: mnist.train.images, Y_: mnist.test.labels}
    a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)
```

The total error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_nn1.py", line 71, in <module>
    a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

Caused by op 'Equal', defined at:
  File "deep_nn1.py", line 47, in <module>
    is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y, 1), tf.argmax(Y_, 1)) # one-hot decoding
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 728, in equal
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding training data (number of rows: 55,000) instead of testing data (number of rows: 10,000) in this line:

```
test_data = {X: mnist.train.images, Y_: mnist.test.labels}
```

Just fix it with:

```
test_data = {X: mnist.test.images, Y_: mnist.test.labels}
```

Comment: Cheers very much Oliver